# Give candidate option to create cv when they click apply button

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, stack-overflow-jobs

For candidates who do not have a cv and click apply they are presented with this:

[image]

Feature request: Give the candidate the ability to create an **so cv** at this point in time.  It helps 1) Get them a cv and 2)Avoid the crappy word resumes being uploaded.

This could come in the form of a button right next to the **upload a file** button but I highly recommend making this new button more noticeable then the upload a file button as to steer the candidate to create a cv more important than uploading a 1980s resume.

Bonus points if this could be seamless to the point that after creating your cv you're back at this dialog with the cv attached.

Answer (score 1):

It was a deliberate decision not to create a big button/interrupt the user to create CV in the middle of application. On Careers, we have an option to create a CV post-apply. This is something we'll probably add to the apply process on Jobs.